# C++ update mfc ui on change of data

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm programming an mfc dialog. The `OnInitDialog` method fills my `CListCtrl` and starts a timer:

```
BOOL MyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    mListCtrl.InsertColumn(0, _T("Signal"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 90);
    mListCtrl.InsertColumn(1, _T("Result"), LVCFMT_LEFT, 90);

    MyList* myList = GetList();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < myList->Size(); i++) {
        MyObject* o = myList->operator[](i);

        int nIndex = mResultList.InsertItem(0, _T(o->GetName()));
        mListCtrl.SetItemText(nIndex, 1, _T(o->GetResult()));
    }
    m_nTimer = SetTimer(1234, 200, NULL);
    return true;
}
```

This works so far...

In the `OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEVENT)` I call `UpdateData(false);`

```
void MyDialog::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{ 
  UpdateData(false);
}
```

I need this timer, because a background thread is modifying the list returned by `GetList()` and I want to display changes immediately. (I was hoping this works somehow like databinding in WWPF).

But the refresh of my view only happens when the dialog is re-initialized.

I guess this is because `InsertItem()` takes a `LPCTSTR` and not a `char*`? 
Can anybody explain a way how to fix this issue please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your `OnTimer` function?  Put the code that fills the list (basically the part from `MyList* myList = GetList();` on) into a separate function and call that function in `OnInitDialog` and in `OnTimer`. `UpdateData` doesn't do anything for `CListCtrl`s. `InsertItem()` takes a `LPCTSTR` and not a `char*` is unrelated.

Comment: @Jabberwocky But that would fill the CListCtrl everytime OnTimer is called. What I want to do is fill the Control once the Dialog is initialized and update the view in the OnTimer()

Comment: You need to write the update function yourself. Compare the new content (`mResultList`) to the actual list content and update only differences.  That shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: BTW: the `_T(...)` like in `_T(o->GetName())` is pointless. The `_T` is only useful for string literals like `_T("Some string")`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky thank you. I'm pretty new to C++ ...

Comment: The `_T` macro is unrelated to C++ it's a Windows thing. Long story....

Comment: Does using `UpdateWindow` cause it to refresh?